# 404 Not found with $_Server ['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, html, forms

I made a connection with a database to send a form to the data base but when I use my submit-button it says:"Not Found

The requested URL /php/GIP/' $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ' was not found on this server."

```
echo '<td><form action=" \' $_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\'] \' " method="POST" class="Keuze">
        <select  name="Keuze"> 
        <option>0</option> 
        <option>1</option> 
        <option>2</option> 
        <option>3</option> 
        <option>4</option> 
        <option>5</option> 
        </select> 
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bestellen"></p> 
        </form></td>';
```

How do I fix this so it can find it and if I want to use a different file than this file I already work in how should I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the resulting HTML - it looks like you are embedding the actual PHP code and not the evaluated value.

Comment: You should avoid using direct url in action.. it might lead to XSS or use urlencode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is couple of things wrong with your string formation.

```
 action=" \' $_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\'] \' " 
          ^-----------^---------^---^--- you have escaped the 
 terminating single quotes causing the string to not terminate. 
 also you have escape the single quotes in key association. also
 you have included the variable inside a single quote block causing the 
 variable not to expand. the result is a literal  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ' 
 being displayed.
```

the proper way to handle this situation would be as follows

```
echo '<td><form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" .....
```

Comment: This works for in this page but if I want to redirect to a different page what should I put in the place of 'PHP_SELF'?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td><form action=" '. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .' " method="POST" class="Keuze">
        <select  name="Keuze"> 
        <option>0</option> 
        <option>1</option> 
        <option>2</option> 
        <option>3</option> 
        <option>4</option> 
        <option>5</option> 
        </select> 
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bestellen"></p> 
        </form></td>';
```

you must join strings